# Wordpress language change [front end Arabic and back end English ]

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I am going to build a website using wordpress , in which i need the back end in English as it is now , and front end in Arabic  .My client going to add post in Arabic language , but he need the back end in English , he add all the post detail in Arabic . How i do this ? Because in Arabic we read from right to left , but in English we read from left to right. And also the all things in front end need to adjust right to left , but default it is left to right .
please Help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 3 steps should work for you:

> 1- Install latest standard Wordpress copy.
> 2- Admin > Settings >
>   Site Language: English.
>  3- Find Arabic RTL theme and upload it
>   from Admin > Appearance > Install themes > Upload, or upload it
>   directly by FTP to theme folder.

Comment: Thank you . Is there any other way ?

Comment: If you found another solution plz post it here.